# Show that $f(x^2)$ has a derivative at $x = 0$, when $f(x)$ doesn't and$|f'(x)|\leq 3 $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function that has a derivative defined everywhere except at x=0, and:

$$|f'(x)| \leq3$$

Show that function $g(x) = f(x^2)$ has a derivative at the point$x=0$, and define $g'(0)$.

Comment: What do you mean by _define_ $g(x)$? You already defined it as $f(x^2)$,

Comment: @quasi Should have been $g'(x)$. Edited now.

Comment: Sorry -- ignore my now deleted answer -- I misread the question.

Comment: But you want more than just g'(0), right? You want the actual definition of g'(x), yes?

Comment: It seems that we need to know more. Example: $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\le 0$. Then $g$ is not even continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @quasi yes the function is supposed to be continuous, edited again.

Comment: @Dole: Your last comment was intended, it appears, as a reply to A.G.

Comment: @Dole: But my question was whether the goal was only to find $g'(0)$ or to find $g'(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Quasi Apologies, only for $g'(0)$

Comment: @Dole: In that case, Fred's answer is what you want.

Comment: Without continuity of $f$ the same is true if we can redefine $g(0)$ because $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ can be proved to exist (for $x_n\to 0$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy from MVT).

Answer (score 4):

Let $x \ne 0$. By the mean value theorem there is $t \in (0,x^2)$ such that

$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0}*x=f'(t)*x$.

Hence

$|\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}| \le 3|x|$.

This gives: $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=0$. Hence $g$ has a derivative at $x=0$ and $g'(0)=0$

Edit: My arguments are not valid, since we need that f is continuous at $0$.

But I saw that the assertion is not valid:

Let $f$ be defined by

$f(0):=0$ and $f(x):=1$ if $x \ne 0$.

Then $g=f$ is not differentiable at $0$

Edit 2: my counterexample does not work anymore, since Dole had made an edit: $f$ is continuous.

So my first proof is O.K.

Comment: Don't you have to prove that $g$ is continuous at $x=0$ first to use the mean value theorem?

Comment: Ooops, you are right !